# Маршрутизация ASP.NET NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, маршрутизация

Известно что в `RouteConfig.cs` можно настроить маршруты. Так же с помощью префиксов можно задать псевдонимы маршрутов, например для `controller=home` и `action=index` задать маршрут `shop/tv`. Есть стандартный хелпер `Html.ActionLink()`, который создает тег со ссылкой.
Есть ли такая реализация хелпера подобного `ActionLink()`, только чтобы при прописывании (к примеру) `controller=home` и `action=index`, непосредственно в представление подставлялось `shop/tv`?

Comment: А `shop` - это контроллер, а `tv` - это экшен у вас или нет?

Comment: Нет, home- это контролер, а index - это действие. Только для этого маршрута псевдоним shop/tv. Тоесть при получении маршрута shop/tv сработает index() в контроллере home

Comment: @SergG Если грамотно настроить, то `ActionLink` будет все выводить так, как нужно. Протестировал у себя (правда ASP.Net Core), есть контроллер - `Agent` (это часть API моего сайта, у него стоит атрибут `[Route("api/v2/[controller]")]`), у него есть экшен `GetVersions` (имеет атрибут `[HttpGet("[action]")]`). Ну и использую `ActionLink` самым простым способом - `@Html.ActionLink("Test", "GetVersions", "Agent")` и результатом становица путь, который уже преобразован при помаши атрибутов, то есть `/api/v2/Agent/GetVersions`, а не `/Agent/GetVersions`. Вывод - `ActionLink` решает вашу задачу.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, благодарю!